# Select Into query adding a second count column with different clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query as follows which works fine :

```
select id_matched
     , count(*) s_count
  into STEVEN_1c 
  from batch 
 where match = 200 
 group by 
       id_matched
```

Now I want to add a second count column on this query which a slightly more specific query which also checks another column i.e. adding a column called "count_unique" where column "unique" = 1.

So something like

```
select id_matched
     , count(*) s_count
     , count(* + and unique=1) count_unique
  into STEVEN_1c 
  from batch 
 where match = 200 
 group by 
       id_matched
```

Just not sure what the syntax would be for adding a second count column which is more specific than the first one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select id_matched
     , count(*) s_count
     , sum(case when unique = 1 then 1 else 0 end) count_unique
  into STEVEN_1c 
  from batch 
 where match = 200 
 group by 
       id_matched
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a case condition in count function as below:

```
select id_matched
, count(*) s_count
, count(case [unique] when 1 then 1 else null end) as count_unique
into STEVEN_1c 
from batch 
where match = 200 
group by 
id_matched
```